# How to change the way shading looks on cubes in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm creating a little game using [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) and everything is going well apart from shome shading issues with cubes. I'm basically building a game level by just dropping textured cubes down to form a maze. The problem is that when the cubes are next to one another, each one is shaded in such a way that it looks as if it's a separate entity and not part of a larger wall.

Here is an example, notice the illusion of a single wall is lost:

[image]

Is there a different shading technique i should use or is there a nice property to be set somewhere to change this shading behavior?

This is my cube model:

```
{

    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3,
        "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.60 Exporter",
        "vertices"      : 8,
        "faces"         : 6,
        "normals"       : 8,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : 4,
        "materials"     : 1,
        "morphTargets"  : 0
    },

    "scale" : 1.000000,
    "materials": [{
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "WallCube",
        "colorAmbient" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        "colorDiffuse" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.15, 0.15, 0.15],
        "mapDiffuse" : "../../textures/walls/stone/stone.png",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "mapNormal" : "../../textures/walls/stone/stone_normal.png",
        "mapNormalFactor" : 1.0,
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 25,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "vertexColors" : false
    }],

    "vertices": [50.000000,-50.000000,-50.000000,50.000000,-50.000000,50.000000,-50.000000,-50.000000,50.000000,-50.000000,-50.000000,-50.000000,50.000000,50.000000,-50.000000,50.000000,50.000000,50.0000050,-50.000000,50.000000,50.000000,-50.000000,50.000000,-50.000000],

    "morphTargets": [],

    "normals": [1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000],

    "colors": [],

    "uvs": [[0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000]],

    "faces": [43,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,43,4,7,6,5,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,43,0,4,5,1,0,1,2,3,0,0,4,7,1,43,1,5,6,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,7,6,2,43,2,6,7,3,0,1,2,3,0,2,6,5,3,43,4,0,3,7,0,3,0,1,2,4,0,3,5]

}
```

and this is how i load it:

```
JSONLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

Light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
Light.position = {x:0, y:75, z:350};

Meshes = [];
JSONLoader.load("../assets/models/cube.js", function(Geometry)
{
    for (var MeshIndex = 0; MeshIndex <= 5; MeshIndex++)
    {
        Meshes[MeshIndex] = new THREE.Mesh(Geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
        Meshes[MeshIndex].position.x = MeshIndex * 100;
        Scene.add(Meshes[MeshIndex]);
    }
});

Scene.add(Light);
```

Any ideas how to make the cubes look like a continuous wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONLoader.load("../assets/models/cube.js", function(Geometry)
{
    Geometry.materials[ 0 ].shading = THREE.FlatShading;

    // ...
}
```

This was kindly answered by alteredq over at the three.js site.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1258#issuecomment-3834489